# Estilar la mitad de un caracter

Tags: javascript, css, css3

¿Exite alguna manera de estilar solo la mitad de un caracter? Por ejemplo, la mitad de un color y la otra mitad de otro.

¿Existe una solución CSS o JavaScript para esto, o habría que recurrir a imágenes?

(se que existe el degradado, pero no buscamos degradar, sino mitad rojo mitad verde por ejemplo de la letra X a un tamaño considerable).

Comment: Te paso un enlace que he encontrado: [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character)

Comment: @Flowen la idea es traducir esa respuesta o mejorarla con nuevo contenido. Si no responde nadie, lo hare yo y la pondre de wiki.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sé que pones que no quieres degradado sino sólo dos colores... la cosa es que puedes usar el degradado de CSS "sin degradado", sólo para que haya dos colores.

El degradado funciona de manera automática: indicas un color de inicio, colores intermedios opcionales y un color final, y el navegador se encargará de hacer la transición de un color a otro. Ahora, si como colores intermedios indicas que quieres el color inicial y el final, entonces el efecto de degradado desaparece quedando sólo los dos colores deseados.

La idea sería poner el primer color en el 0 y 0.5, y el color final en el 0.5 y 1. De ese modo no hay degradado, sino que se salta de uno al otro directamente:

```css
.dos-colores {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.dos-colores > span {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f00), color-stop(0.5, #f00), color-stop(0.5, #0a0), color-stop(1, #0a0));
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f00), color-stop(0.5, #f00), color-stop(0.5, #0a0), color-stop(1, #0a0));
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="dos-colores">
  <span>H</span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>L</span>
  <span>A</span>
</div>
```

Éste método es más limpio y permite más flexibilidad (podrías tener tantos colores como quisieras sin la limitación del número de pseudo-elementos), pero tiene el inconveniente de que su soporte puede no ser tan bueno (seguramente falle en las versiones de IE anteriores a la 10, y puede que necesites los prefijos de navegador para que funcione en todos).

Y se podría simplificar un poco más usando [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) en lugar de `gradient`, haciéndolo más fácil de leer:

```css
.dos-colores {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.dos-colores > span {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #f00 50%, #0a0 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f00 50%, #0a0 50%);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="dos-colores">
  <span>H</span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>L</span>
  <span>A</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No conocia esta opción del degradado! Muy buena, gracias :)

Comment: @blonfu Gracias por la sugerencia, la he añadido al snippet.

Answer (score 6):

Una opción sencilla sería hacer uso de los pseudo elementos `::before` o `::after`para esto.

La idea sería escribir la letra y usando, por ejemplo `::before`, escribir la misma letra encima con otro color, posicionándola exactamente encima de la letra original (con `position: absolute`) y ocultando el sobrante (con  `oveflow: hidden`). De ese modo una parte de la letra visible será el pseudo-elemento y la otra mitad el elemento original.

Para que la letra aparezca con la mitad derecha de un color y la mitad izquierda de otro (división horizontal de colores) haría falta que el pseudo-elemento ocupase el 50% del ancho. Si lo que quieres es que aparezca una división vertical de colores, entonces sería un 50% del alto.

Aquí puedes verlo funcionando:

```css
.letras-partidas span {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.letras-partidas span::before {
  content: attr(data-letra);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: red;
}

.letras-partidas.vertical span::before {
  content: attr(data-letra);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="letras-partidas">
  <span data-letra="H">H</span>
  <span data-letra="O">O</span>
  <span data-letra="L">L</span>
  <span data-letra="A">A</span>
</div>

<div class="letras-partidas vertical">
  <span data-letra="C">C</span>
  <span data-letra="A">A</span>
  <span data-letra="R">R</span>
  <span data-letra="A">A</span>
  <span data-letra="C">C</span>
  <span data-letra="O">O</span>
  <span data-letra="L">L</span>
  <span data-letra="A">A</span>
</div>
```

<sup>*</sup>Si el texto va a ocupar una única fila, entonces se podría simplificar el ejemplo con los colores verticales, aplicando los estilos directamente al contenedor sin necesidad de tener tantas etiquetas.

---

A partir de eso, puedes hacer ejemplos más elaborados:

¿Quieres que en lugar de 2 colores sean 3? Usan `::before` y `::after` y en lugar del 50%, haz que los pseudo-elementos ocupen un 66% y 33% respectivamente:

```css
.letras-partidas span {
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.letras-partidas span::before,
.letras-partidas span::after {
  content: attr(data-letra);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 66%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: red;
}

.letras-partidas span::after {
  color: blue;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="letras-partidas">
  <span data-letra="H">H</span>
  <span data-letra="O">O</span>
  <span data-letra="L">L</span>
  <span data-letra="A">A</span>
</div>
```